# Deleting a property of an object inside its definition; Why?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Looking at the recent Google Maps API loader [source](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js), I'm wondering what is the purpose of the following:

```
google.maps.Load = function(apiLoad) {
    delete google.maps.Load;
    ...
```

Why would you `delete` a property of an object, inside its definition? I suspect it could have some performance increase, but can't figure out how a property can delete itself inside its definition.

Comment: `delete` **always** makes things slower (at least in V8). In that case it likely cleans itself up so that it was not possible to accidentally `Load` it twice. If this assumption is valid then the better solution would be to reassign it to an empty function: `google.maps.Load = function() {};`

Comment: @zerkms well, I thought it's gonna free up some memory, hence increasing the overall performance -- even though it might be a slow call. Is that right?

Comment: That is not right. See http://debuggable.com/posts/understanding-hidden-classes-in-v8:4c7e81e4-1330-4398-8bd2-761bcbdd56cb for details.

Comment: `google.maps.Load = function() { throw new Error("Already loaded") };` seems more robust.

Comment: @zerkms, why empty function instead `null` or `undefiend`?

Comment: @Grundy well, it depends on the aim, actually. It's not better indeed.

Comment: @Sam would you mind posting your comment as an answer as well?  cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is to ensure that the API is only loaded once. However, this will not throw a useful error when the function is called a second time, but it may cause an exception.

Here is an alternative solution which throws a more useful error.

```
google.maps.Load = function() { throw new Error("Already loaded") };
```

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as it originally provided this solution.

Answer (score 5):

Obviously we can only make assumptions since it's only that code author can say for sure.

If the reason was to ensure that the `Load` procedure is performed just once then the decision chosen is really poor.

The problem is that deletion of properties makes impossible V8 (and may be other engines) to use so called "hidden classes" (which is an optimisation method for faster object's properties lookup).

The better alternative would be

```
google.maps.Load = function() {};
```

or

```
google.maps.Load = function() { throw new Error("Already loaded") };
```

as suggested by [@Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/711601/sam) in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201029/deleting-a-property-of-an-object-inside-its-definition-why/32201226#comment52286668_32201029).

References:

- [Understanding hidden classes in v8](http://debuggable.com/posts/understanding-hidden-classes-in-v8:4c7e81e4-1330-4398-8bd2-761bcbdd56cb)
- [Fast Property Access](https://developers.google.com/v8/design?csw=1#prop_access)

Comment: very interesting information here, thanks a lot for sharing these.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say to only allow to be *loaded* once.

Comment: That make sense! Wouldn't it be better to place it in the end of the definition rather in the very first line?

Comment: Better from what perspective?

Comment: @Mahdi IMO it's more transparent at the top, i.e. *this is a one-off function*, I'd do the very same :)